# ASP.NET MVC: Razor @helper vs extension methods to HtmlHelper - which is preferred?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

The Razor view engine in ASP.NET MVC supports @helper to define little helper methods. It seems you can do much the same by adding extension methods to HtmlHelper. In what situations is it best to use each?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subjective question, so here's my subjective and biased answer: When the helper code involves amounts of C# code use a custom HtmlHelper and when it's primary markup you could use `@helper`. But assuming that when you have markup you could use a partial like `@Html.Partial("_foo", SomeModel)` or an editor/display templates like `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)`, the `@helper` doesn't really have any practical use. Personally I've never used `@helper` by the way, and I've never recommended it's usage to people I've been consulting.

Comment: This has been my thought, especially where the example of it http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx for DisplayPrice, i think this is the type of code it's best suited for. Almost completely logicless code that just affects presentation. Similarly would be to make your views DRYer.

Comment: If the view engine changes we don't have to rewrite helper methods in .cs but in declarative way (.cshtml) we have to.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's true, though the @helpers seem a bit easier to work with if there's a good chunk of markup that's included--Html extensions and more extensive markup don't go that well together, IMO.

On the other hand, @helpers can't be unit tested like Html extensions.